# Change the terminal in pycharm from sh to usual

Tags: python, terminal, pycharm

I use usual community pycharm, I create the projects with 'venv', but 2 days ago I had a problem, my terminal was changed from usual one to the terminal that looks like this

```
sh-3.2$ pip install 
sh: pip: command not found
sh-3.2$ /
sh: /: is a directory
```

Actually I do not remember that I changed something in settings. It happened only to terminal in pycharm, terminal in system did not change.
So my question is what happened to my terminal, and how to change it back into terminal that will look like this:

```
(`base) {name of account} ~ %`
```

information about pycharm:
PyCharm 2020.3.3 (Community Edition)
Build #PC-***.****.**, built on January 27, 2021
Runtime version: 11.0.9.1+11-b1145.77 x86_64
VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o.
macOS 10.15.7
GC: ParNew, ConcurrentMarkSweep
Memory: 990M
Cores: 4

I have MacOS

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Go into `Settings` > `Tools` > `Terminal` and check the shell path. It should match your shell path from system terminal. You can find out your shell path with

```
echo $SHELL
# My Output
/usr/bin/zsh
```

Answer (score 0):

I've just had the same issue.
The "usual one" you meant is the bash shell.
I solved it by changing the zsh shell into bash, by running the command:
chsh -s /bin/bash